# Transferring files from one blob to another through vnet in azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-blob-storage, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a requirement where I need to transfer files from one blob to the other through vnets deployed in different geographies and connected to each other. As I am very new to Azure platform, I tried researching over the web but could not find any proper solution. I got a suggestion that I can achieve this through programming an app service. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: Could you be more specific ? do you need to copy all files ? everytime a file is created ? why do you need to use a vnet ?

Comment: @Thomas I want to copy the files every time a file is created. I want to use the vnet because of the sensitivity of the data

Comment: storage account uses https, I feel it's an overkill to use vnet for that ... Will post an answer soon

Comment: Thank you @Thomas

Comment: One more question, are you just creating a backup of the files or is there any other reason to copy all the files from one storage account to another /

Comment: @Thomas I am creating a backup

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your scenario, here are options:

- To perform a backup of the storage account across different gegions, you can just specify the `replication` parameter (while creating a new storage account) to one these values:

  - [Geo-redundant storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy-grs)
  - [Read-access geo-redundant storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy-grs#read-access-geo-redundant-storage)

  Another article on HA applications:

  - [Designing Highly Available Applications using RA-GRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-designing-ha-apps-with-ragrs)
- If you want to manually copy files from a storage account to another, you can use Azure Storage events, it will push an event to [Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/) every time a blob is created.

  - [Reacting to Blob storage events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview)

  You can then use a [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/) or a [Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) to copy blobs to another storage account.